# Sounds Doesnt Play Java

Tags: java, audio

i now learning to do sound and im making a game im trying to get an audio file to play when i start it 
 this is my code when i run it the sound doesnt work can i get some help?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;


public class RunGame extends Applet
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //get new game system 
        GameSystem game = GameSystem.getInstance(); 
        URL url = GameSystem.class.getResource("sound/theme.mp3");
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        clip.loop();
        game.run(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.  Are you sure that the MP3 you're playing exists at that path?  2.  Are you sure that your speakers are plugged in and turned up sufficiently?

Comment: The regular JRE doesn't play mp3.

Comment: i changed it to a wav file and it still didnt work and yes i am sure it exists there